# ESLint not working for json import when using experimental-json-modules

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have the following in my package.json...

```
"lint:fix": "node --experimental-json-modules ./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.mjs --fix"
```

And the following in my code

```
import pkgjson from "../package.json" assert { type: 'json' };
```

But when I run the lint command I see...

```
1:39  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token assert
```

How do I use json imports with eslint?

Comment: Eslint Support of `assert {type: "json"}` [Eslint discussion thread ](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15305#discussioncomment-1634740) In the discussion thread you can find several alternatives to solve this problem